# Preferences / Display Preferences missing in Gnome 3.12

Tags: gnome, system-settings

I just installed Gnome 3.12 on Ubuntu 14.04 via the standard PPA.  It appears that the Display Preferences and Preferences applications are either missing, or missing from the application search menu.

How do I change my screen configuration and other preferences in Gnome 3.12?  Alternatively, how do I launch the Display Preferences and Preferences applications?  I don't know of any applications in bin that correspond to these apps?

Comment: Do you have `gnome-settings-daemon` installed?

Comment: It is installed, but didn't run when I tried to execute it from the terminal.  It appears there is an update for it that wasn't downloaded when I followed the ppa instruction steps, so I'm going to try that.

Comment: @Seth Updating gnome-settings-daemon fixed and restarting gnome fixed the issue.  Is there a list of all packages that I should update to ensure a less-broken experience in the future? Feel free to add an answer, and I'll mark yours as the resolution.

Comment: That would depend on how you installed gnome (more specific that just "the standard PPA"), explicit commands, etc. It was probably just a glitch. Did you have gnome installed before installing 3.12?

Comment: Yes, I was running Gnome 3.10 before installing.  I did the following: https://gist.github.com/nikolawannabe/5c104b5ac1d32b4acea9 to install 3.12.

Comment: Ah, yeah that's one way of doing it, but like you found out, doesn't always get everything ;) Next time I'd remove gnome 2.10 and do a fresh gnome install for the next version.

Comment: @Seth Sorry to keep asking...Is there a preferred way to uninstall all of gnome?

Comment: Not that I know of. It is usually a meta package, so it can be tricky. I think you should be fine now though.

Answer (score 3):

Try `gnome-control-center appearance` from Terminal. If it won't launch settings paste output here.

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct binary to launch.  I'm not sure whether or not it would have worked before I updated gnome-settings-daemon or not, and I think that was the correct resolution of the issue.

Comment: [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7493233/) is copy of my .desktop file. You can put it in ~/.local/share/applications or /usr/share/applications in file named whatever.desktop